# Cache-Control Headers not respected on CloudFlare

Tags: caching, nginx, cache-control, cloudflare

I am trying to get some html pages to be cached, the same way images are automatically cached via CloudFlare but I can't get CloudFlare to actually hits its cache for html.

According to the documentation (Ref: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/202775670-How-Do-I-Tell-CloudFlare-What-to-Cache-), it's possible to cache anything with a Cache-Control set to `public` with a `max-age` greater than 0.

I've tried various combinations of headers on my origin Nginx server without success. From a simple `Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000` to more complex headers including `s-maxage=31536000`, `Pragma: public`, `ETag: "569ff137-6"`, `Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT` without any results.

Any ideas to force CloudFlare to serve the html pages from their cache?

PS: I am getting the `CF-Cache-Status: HIT` on the images and it works fine but on the html pages nothing, not even `CF-Cache-Status: something`. With a CloudFlare page rule for html pages, it seems to work fine but I want to avoid using one, mainly because it's too CloudFlare specific. I am not serving cookies or anything dynamic from these pages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is now possible to get Cloudflare to respect your web servers headers instead of overriding them with the minimum described in the Browser Cache TTL setting.

Firstly navigate to the Caching tab in the Cloudflare dashboard:

[image: Cloudflare Dashboard Caching tab]

From here you can scroll down to the "Browser Cache Expiration" setting, from here you can select the "Respect Existing Headers" option in the dropdown:

[image: Respect Existing Headers Cloudflare]

**Further reading:**

- [Does CloudFlare honor my Expires and Cache-Control headers for static content?](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169266)
- [Caching Anonymous Page Views](https://blog.cloudflare.com/caching-anonymous-page-views/)
- [How do I cache static HTML?](http://How%20do%20I%20cache%20static%20HTML?)

**Note:** If this setting isn't chosen, Cloudflare will apply a default 4 hour minimum to Cache-Control headers. Once this setting is set, Cloudflare will not touch your Cache-Control headers (even if they're low or not at all set).

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled on this too.  From the page it says

*Pro Tip: Sending cache directives from your origin for resources with extensions we don't cache by default will make absolutely no difference. To specify the caching duration at your origin for the extensions we don't cache by default, you'd have to create a Page Rule to "Cache Everything".*

So it appears that you do have to set a page rule to use this for files that CloudFlare doesn't cache by default.  This page describes this in more detail,

https://blog.cloudflare.com/edge-cache-expire-ttl-easiest-way-to-override/

That said it still didn't work for me and appears not to be supported.  After contacting their support they confirmed this. Respect Origin Header has been removed from all plan types.  So if you have no page rules they will respect the origin header.

This doesn't help for hitting their edge cache for html pages however.  To that you have set up a page rule.  Once that is done you can, I believe, set your max-age as low as your plan allows.  Any lower and it gets over-written.  That is to say, with no page rule you could say Cache-Control: max-age:30 and it would pass through.  With a page rule that include edge caching your max-age then becomes subject to the minimum time your plan allows even if the page rule doesn't specify browser cache.

Comment: I have an open ticket about this right now. It seems to be impossible to do something as simple as respecting cache header on all URLs. Either you don't include a page rule, meaning only stylesheets etc are cached respecting the origin's header OR you create a simple "Cache everything" page rule and suddenly origin headers are ignored!

Comment: Not totally ignored.  Just ignored to the extent they are shorter than what your plan allows.

Answer (score 0):

The CF documentation is very unclear.  Go into "Page Rules", and define a rule that turns on caching, based upon wildcards -- and then it will work.